# Merge all worksheets used data range to a new sheet named “Master”

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with many sheets with fixed data structure.

I want to:
First: Fill the last empty column with the sheet name on all sheets.
Second: Delete columns B, C, D, E, F (5 columns) on all sheets.
Third: Merge all worksheets used data range to a new sheet named “Master”.

INPUT DATA:

```
PARTICULARS H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9  H10 H11 H12 H14 H15
AA          1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  
BB          14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  
CC          27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
```

SHEET NAME: |ECSTASY|BEAUTY|  etc,

```
OUTPUT DATA:
PARTICULAR H6   H7  H8  H9  H10 H11 H12 H14 H15
AA          6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  ECSTASY
BB          19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  ECSTASY
CC         32   33  34  35  36  37  38  39  ECSTASY
AA         6    7   8   9   10  11  12  13  BEAUTY
BB        19    20  21  22  23  24  25  26  BEAUTY
CC        32    33  34  35  36  37  38  39  BEAUTY
etc.
```

I developed code. It is giving the following error

> Application defined or Object defined error

on the line

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(srcLastRow, srcLastCol - 5)).Copy masterWs.Cells(destLastRow, 1)
```

```vb
Sub CombineSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim masterWs As Worksheet
Dim srcLastRow As Long, srcLastCol As Long
Dim destLastRow As Long

' Create the "Master" sheet
Set masterWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
masterWs.Name = "Master"

' Iterate through each worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Master" Then
        ' Fill the last empty column with the sheet name
        srcLastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        ws.Cells(1, srcLastCol).Value = ws.Name
        
        ' Delete columns B, C, D, E, and F
        ws.Range("B:F").Delete
        
        ' Find the last row in the source and destination sheets
        srcLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        destLastRow = masterWs.Cells(masterWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        ' Copy the data from the source sheet to the "Master" sheet
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(srcLastRow, srcLastCol - 5)).Copy masterWs.Cells(destLastRow, 1)
    End If
Next ws

' Clean up
Set ws = Nothing
Set masterWs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Combine Worksheets into a Master Worksheet

[image]

```vb
Sub CombineSheets()
        
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Master"
    Const DELETE_COLUMNS As String = "B:F"
    Const DST_SHEET_COLUMN_TITLE As String = "Sheet"
        
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dsh As Object
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dsh = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
            dsh.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet, rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    Dim dws As Worksheet, dfCell As Range, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        If IsFirstFound Then ' copy all but the 1st worksheet's data only
            With sws.UsedRange
                rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
                If rCount > 0 Then
                    .Resize(rCount).Offset(1).Copy dfCell
                End If
            End With
        Else ' copy the 1st worksheet (with headers)
            sws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count) ' or Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
            Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count) ' or wb.Sheets(1)
            dws.Name = DST_SHEET
            With dws.UsedRange
                rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
                cCount = .Columns.Count
                With .Cells(1).Offset(, cCount - 1)
                    .Copy .Offset(, 1)
                    .Offset(, 1).Value = DST_SHEET_COLUMN_TITLE
                End With
            End With
            Set dfCell = dws.Range("A2")
            IsFirstFound = True
        End If
        If rCount > 0 Then
            dfCell.Offset(, cCount).Resize(rCount).Value = sws.Name
            Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(rCount)
        End If
    Next sws
    
    dws.Columns(DELETE_COLUMNS).Delete xlShiftToLeft
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Sheets combined into a Master sheet.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You are a genius. Your code snippet works like a charm and fully meets the stated requirements. My heartfelt thanks. Would you be kind enough to point out what general mistakes were there causing Run-time error '1004'

Comment: The last rows need to be between 1 and 1048576 while the last columns need to be between 1 and 16384 (1 and 65536, and 1 and 256 respectively for older versions). Debug your code after the error occurs and hover over the variable names to investigate. The column `srcLastCol - 5` is probably 0 or less.